# Function pointer reference

Tags: c++, function-hooking, pointer

I need to hook 10/20 functions like these:

```
static void* __cdecl HookFunction1(char *FileName, int a2, int a3, int a4);


 __declspec(naked)  void HookFunction2(char  *Src, int pedx, int 
    
    a3, int a4, int a5, int a6);
    
 static BOOL HookFunction3(int a1, DWORD *a2, DWORD *a3, int a4, char a5, int a6);
```

and I use this code:

```
switch (int iD)
{
case 1

    DetourAttach(&(LPVOID&)AddressOfHook, &HookFunction1);

case 2
   DetourAttach(&(LPVOID&)AddressOfHook, &HookFunction2);

case 3
   DetourAttach(&(LPVOID&)AddressOfHook, &HookFunction3);
.....
}
```

but I like to not repeat x times "DetourAttach" and I like do to something like this:

```
switch (int iD)
{
case 1

    HookFunction = &HookFunction1;

case 2
    HookFunction = &HookFunction2;

case 3
   HookFunction = &HookFunction3;
.....
}

DetourAttach(&(LPVOID&)AddressOfHook, &HookFunction);
```

I ask if there is a easy way to do this becouse is more flexible.

Thanks !!

Answer (score 0):

I have solved myself.

```
PVOID HookFunction;

HookFunction = (PVOID)HookFunction1;
```

and

```
DetourAttach(&(LPVOID&)AddressOfHook, HookFunction);
```